# unknown error arriving after the compiling and running of this c program

Tags: c, function, switch-statement

I have written this code and tried to compile it in codeblocks, using  default GCC compiler.
When giving option 1, I am getting this output "hello world6356744".
Please explain what is happening.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int fun1(int x,int y)
{
printf("hello world");
return x+y;
}
int fun2()
{
return 0;
}


int main()
{
printf("type 1 for * or type 2 for #");
int a;
scanf("%d", &a);

int ca1;

switch(a)
{
case 1:

    ca1=fun1(2,3);
    printf("%d", &ca1);
    break;

case 2:
    fun2();
    break;
default:
    printf("invalid input");

}
return 0;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5PhT.png

Comment: What do you expect it to do? That output is what I would expect

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the address of the pointer with & on line 28. Remove the & and printf should work correctly. Printf does not take an address, instead it takes the value.

When reading input using scanf, that is when you provide the address of the variable/pointer because scanf directly modifies the variable/pointer you pass into it.

Comment: No problem, even seasoned c and c++ developers run into this issue. There are whole chapters in books dedicated to "Passing variables by reference" and "passing variables by value".